# creating a table with colspan in the php

Tags: php, html

I have created a database and different tables in that database.
 Now when i tries to create a table to display it in browser using html in my php file , 
its throwing some errors. 
I am using colspan property in my table. 
When i am running my php file its showing like "unexpected 2 in line number 16".

```
<html>   
<head>
</head>
<body>  
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "final_database";
        $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        mysql_select_db("final_database");
        echo "<table border=1>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">parametr_1</th> //line number 16
            <th colspan="2">parameter_2</th>
            <th colspan="2">parameter_3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>subhead1</th>
            <th>subhead2</th>
            <th>subhead3</th>
            <th>subhead4</th>
            <th>subhead5</th>
            <th>subhead6</th>
        </tr>";
    echo "<tr>";    
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
echo "<table border=1>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan='2'>parametr_1</th> 
            <th colspan='2'>parameter_2</th>
            <th colspan='2'>parameter_3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>subhead1</th>
            <th>subhead2</th>
            <th>subhead3</th>
            <th>subhead4</th>
            <th>subhead5</th>
            <th>subhead6</th>
        </tr>";
    echo "<tr>";    
    echo "</table>";
```

Use single quote instead of double.

Comment: its working ...thanks ...:)

Comment: u got or not, why it was not working @Akshay ?

Comment: when i was using double quotes instead of single quotes , it wasn't working ....now its working ... @Danish